# item id of last item in osclass classified script

Tags: php, osclass

I am using osclass classified script, I want to get item id of the last item.

so far i tried following code but it do not work

```
$lastItem[] = View::newInstance()->_get('search_end');
echo $lastItem[0]['pk_i_id'];
```

anybody tell me whats wrong with it, or guide me to the right direction.

Comment: At least show `print_r($lastItem)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the latest items.

```
if (osc_has_latest_items()):
    echo osc_item_id();
endif;
```

It uses the `::getLastestItems()` method from the search model object that defaults to descending order. So the first item in the latest items list is actually the most recent.

However be advised that it will overwrite the 'standard' item loop, so don't use it within a `while (osc_has_items()):` for example.